# {state: pening} is returned when try to getText() of Web element

Tags: javascript, appium

I am using Mocha framework with Javascript to automate a Mobile Hybrid application.

On a web page i am using a collection object to get the text of all object but intead of retuning the text it returns {state: pending}. I am new to Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getText(){
this.driver.elementsByXPath("//h3[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]", config.iWait, 100).then(function(ele) {
    var size = objectSize(ele);
    console.log(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         var txts = (ele[i].text());
          console.log(txts);
    }
})
```

};

```
function objectSize() {
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
```

};

Comment: It seems to be a promise, just like the return value of  `elementsByXPath`. Use `ele[i].text().then(function(txts) { console.log(txts); });`

Comment: IBergi, I tried the way you suggssted. It seems that Javascript send all the request for getting text before getting response from the appium to validate.